# Why does my Android Studio main activity screen look like this instead of the Main activity extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does my Android Studio main activity screen look like this instead of   "MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity"?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() 
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because when you have created the new project, while configuring your project you have chosen `Kotlin` as language instead of `Java`.

[image]